# multiple keypress in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, events, keyboard

What I am trying to do is handle an event in which an end user pounds the keyboard with his palm, fist, face, etc. Sounds ridiculous but it will be used as a supplemental safety feature in a high-power laser lab. I was thinking of watching for 4 or more keys. Examples of valid combinations:

```
- u{f5}7hby6
- 6g3.io{alt}mn'
- p9hyi
- {tab}2{f2}56{shift}z
- {alt}{windows}\{ctrl}{f8}
- basically anything else that can be typed with a face
```

I have tried this method, which doesn't work because not all KeyUp or KeyDown events are handled especially when multiple keys are pressed.

```vb
Private keez As New List(Of Integer)

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    keez.Add(e.KeyValue)
    If keez.Count >= 4 Then MessageBox.Show("I handled it!")
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    Try
        keez.Remove(AscW(e.KeyChar))
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    keez.Remove(e.KeyValue)
End Sub
```

With this method, keys are missed constantly. I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to handle multiple keys pressed consecutively. Most Google searches are related to standard key combos which almost always include a modifier (ctrl, alt, shift) + one additional key.

Comment: I do a lot of work on industrial systems (which have just as many risks as a laser lab - used to work in those too) and I have never resorted to this kind of strategy.  I would suggest that any accidental input which may be dangerous require a suitably complex and deliberate action - confirmation dialog, etc.  For one function (with extreme need to not have it happen by accidental input) I've even generated a random 4-digit pin which the user has to correctly reproduce before initiating the action.

Comment: Another safety is to have to hold a key for a determined time (rather than an instantaneous press).  During this time you can verify that no other keys have been pressed (ie: any other key event during the wait time cancels the first)

Comment: J, thanks for the input. I should have included the term "E-STOP" for clarity. This would be a soft E-STOP in addition to the hard E-STOP near the laser.The user should be able only to disable the laser with this method. There is a more complicated deliberate method for enabling the laser.

Comment: hrm...if you need another E-STOP, I'd probably just install another hard E-STOP.  An e-stop box and wire are cheap, highly visible, and extremely reliable.  The above is not reliable.  You would at very least have to ensure your program keeps focus and *disables the windows key* (mashing it first would defeat this).

Comment: My CEO asked for it and at this particular start-up, we try to disagree with him as little as possible :)

Comment: I feel that a good part of my job is telling the chief when his ideas are rubbish.  Firmly so, when needed. ;)  I mean, you could always tie a dog leash around the operator's neck and rope it to the outlet plug powering the laser.  That way, if the fellow passed out or flailed nervously it would yank the cord out of the wall!  Really...sometimes ideas are just bad and you have to call them that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can handle more than 4 keys at the same time (for example, 5 letter characters at the same time will not work) - it is a hardware limitation of most today's keyboards, i.e. how they are wired internally. Keyboards that support all keys pressed at the same time can be very expensive, and I haven't seen one live. You can check [this thread](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-do-i-remove-the-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses) for more information. Also discussed [on tomshardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/50383-28-pressing-multiple-keys-keyboard-problem).

Comment: mechanical keyboards allow more than four (each key is an individual switch).  The limitation affects membrane keyboards (which are by far most of them) due to crosstalk issues, if I recall.